# How to make an Extended Entry Decision Table for Testing

Tags: unit-testing, testing, computer-science, black-box-testing

So I need to make a Decision Table to test a bit of code. The code is simple and straight forward but requires two user inputs to determine two proceeding variables. This is why I need to make this more than a binary (true/false) table.

The user is prompted to input total **income**, this will, in turn, determine which **bracket** the user falls into. Then the user is prompted to input the amount of **dependents**, which will determine the final **tax**. Depending on the income bracket, a switch statement will then set 
**tax** = **income** * [certain percentage]. After this the amount of **dependents** will determine what percentage of the tax will be removed.

Essentially what I need to know is how to set up my **Conditions**, **Actions**, and **Rules**.

[Here is an example of decision table but this one is binary (true/false)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clHjV.png)

I am using Java for the code but that isn't entirely relevant. What I need specifically is deciding what my Conditions should be, whether it's solely income or the combinations of income and dependents, etc. I do not need to write the code, just need to write the test table for it.

If anyone can help inform me as to what I should do or where I should look, that would be appreciated. I am willing to provide anymore information if need be!

Thanks!

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better. Please also clarify what languages you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you understand, what the regular (binary) decision table is, then it'll be easy for you to get the extended table as well - the difference is in conditions only.

**Conditions in the extended decision table can have more than two values**. For example, in your case you have two conditions:

- **Tax Bracket** with values (for example): [0, 9275], [9276, 37650], [37651, 91150] etc.
- **Number of Dependents** with values: 0, 1, 2, 3 etc. (what's the max?)

For **Actions** I'd choose the tax rate and the deduction amount - they depend on the bracket and on the number of dependents correspondingly.

**Rules** (=columns in the table) connect conditions and actions - for all the possible combinations of condition values you have a list of actions to perform. In your case these actions will be simply two numbers, which you will use in a tax formula.

(Frankly I don't see why you need a decision table in this case at all... I think, the tax formula with parameters, depending on income, will be enough)